# using asp:gridview with add new row button in jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view with several template fields (for drop-downs) which is working fine if I place it outside of the DIV what I use as modal dialog. 
Grid has onrowdatabound and OnRowDeleting events and additionally a button to add a new row to the grid. When I tried to move this grid to the Modal dialog the Add button stopped working. The click event is coded in code behind and it does not fire. Can anyone help me to understand how I should handle it?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
<div id="dialog" >

<asp:GridView ID="grPlan" runat="server" 
            ShowFooter="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None"
            onrowdatabound = "GridView_RowDataBound"
            OnRowDeleting = "GridView_RowDeleting" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="id" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Program>">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgModal2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="false" DataTextField="Prog" 
    DataValueField="ProgID" />
            </ItemTemplate >
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EF">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnneeFiscaleModal2"  DataTextField="EtendueLong" DataValueField="EtendueLong" runat="server" 
                AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="false"/>
            </ItemTemplate >
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approbations">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlApprobationModal2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="false" 
    DataTextField="Approb" DataValueField="ApprobationID"/>
            </ItemTemplate >
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fonds">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFondsModal2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" MaxLength="15" Width = "120" onkeypress="return 
    validateFloatKeyPress(this,event);" />
            </ItemTemplate >
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />            
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />

    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

$("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: false,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 520,
                    resizable: false,
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        //debugger;
                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                        $('.ui-dialog').css("left", "400px");
                        $('.ui-dialog').css("top", "300px");
                        $('.ui-dialog').css("position", "absolute");
                    },
                    title: '',
                    buttons: {
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        'OK': function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                });

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can do what you want to do,

1) Wrap your `gridview` inside  `UpdatePanel` and then set the `PostbackTrigger` to the your add button control.

2) You can use the `gridview.RowCommand` event. It handles all button related events inside a cell of a `gridview`.[Here is more info on it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

3) You can use the `jquery` to force the `postback` on the button click using the `__dopostback()`[Here is more info on it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/doPostBack-function).

Comment: HelloThanks a lot for your answer. I have tried the first one since it looked simple- and it didn't work

Comment: I have tried the first one (added postbacktrigget on frond end and after tried on code behind  with script manager). When I open the Modal dialog and click the button- nothing gappens. It does not fire the click event from Jquery dialog. Second option didn't work too. My butto is not in gridview cell- it is in the grid footer or can be placed otside of grid. On click it adds a new row to the grid (with templates fields) and after does a row bound.

Comment: Third option: I messed up. I went through the example and aadded all inputs and function __doPostBack as well as Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]  on page load but when I run my application I am getting an error on document.Form1.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget. If I have no header or body on my page (it is inside of Master) and my html inside of Update panel/contentTemplate).  Should I move this function and Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] to Master? Thank you very much for any help. I have just recently started worling with jQuery and feel lost.